# Use all coordinates in a grid except with certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a minesweeper I have created a board using python and pygame. When you flagged all bombs, you win. I have separate functions that contain the (randomised) bomb positions, and create the numbers around the bombs(on the proper coordinates). How do I make sure it checks the coordinates 0 to GRID_TILES(the maximum range) with the exception of all bomb locations? As those should remain flagged.

I got a function where when you click a bomb, you get shown the entire board. I want the same except for when the coordinates are in my BOMBS[].

```
def show_board():
    for x in range(0,GRID_TILES):
        for y in range(0, GRID_TILES):
            "when" not in BOMBS:
                draw_item(CELLS[x][y], x, y, (x+1,y+1))
```

I want to know if there is a "when" function, and how I could implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then the following should work:

---

If `BOMBS` is a list of tuples, then the following test should work `if (x, y) not in BOMBS:`

The `in` operator works on lists, as well as dicts, sets and tuples - anything that's iterable actually. In general, using it on lists is not such a great idea, because it needs to look through the whole list, in the worst case, to find an element. But for such small lists, it should not be a problem. If you find that it is, make `BOMBS` be a set and you should be good.

Comment: This seems to work, I'll accept it as soon as possible.